# How to add subdomain on local machine

Tags: apache, subdomain, vhosts

I have modified my etc/hosts file (under Windows 7), so that `www.example.com` and `demo.example.com` both point at `localhost`. Unfortunately accessing `demo.example.com`, takes me to localhost's document root (which is logical). I want to change this to point `demo.example.com` to `demo.localhost`, so make a new virtual subdomain on localhost and then the etc/hosts file should do it's work.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I have this vhosts file, which has a valid syntax, but doesn't seem to be working as I want.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerPath /demo-example/
ServerName demo.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the port number like this

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
    ServerPath /demo-example/
    ServerName demo.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Nope, still `demo.example.com` going to `example.com`

Comment: try to add directive 'NameVirtualHost' as `NameVirtualHost *` before virtual virtual hosts directive. read this link [subdomain conf] (http://content.websitegear.com/article/subdomain_setup.htm)